# Make the axis gizmo disappear

Tags: gizmo

[image]

Where do I turn off this enlarged axis display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncheck *"origins"* here:

[image]

Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> shortcut.